# slideUp and slideDown cause a jump in text in Firefox 12?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown

I have a code as below:

```
$(function(){

    $("#ani").slideUp(600,function(){
         $(this).text('13').slideDown(600);        
    });
})
```

And HTML code as below:

```
<div>Comment: <span id="ani">12</span></div>
```

When page has been loaded slide will affect `Comment:` text. [I have written this code in jsFiddle and you can watch it there.](http://jsfiddle.net/uYXMB/2/)
What is the problem. I wrote `display` and `height` css properties for the outer div but gain no success ;(

Comment: `Comment:` will jump with the number. When page is loaded. I want to slide just the number. `Comment:`  should be fixed

Comment: It does. 12 slides down, 13 pops up.

Comment: The problem is `Comments:` will jump a little too. Did you get me?

Comment: Not for me. It stays in its position. What browser?

Comment: Yes, IT jump for me too. FireFox 13.0

Comment: In chrome it's OK! I think problem is from CSS default properties in different browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the below should do it.
The div should have a standard width and the inside span is `float: right`

```
<div>Comment:
    <span id="ani">12</span>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
div{width:100px;}
span{float:right;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VRvuW/1/)

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

This updated is based on OP's answer:

```
<div><span>Comment:</span>
    <span id="ani">12</span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
span{float:left;display:inline-block;min-height:30px;}
```

Comment: BlueBox(12) in the comment should go up. In your demo `12` itself goes up and 13 down.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved! You can see [the output in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRvuW/4/)
Thanks @Dhiraj_Bodicherla, your help solved the problem +1. I actually needed to float the comment to the left as below:

```
<div><span style="float:left;display:inline-block;min-height:30px;">Comment:</span>
    <span id="ani">12</span>
</div>
```

jQuery part:

```
$(function(){

    $("#ani").slideUp(600,function(){
         $(this).text('13').slideDown(600);        
    });
})
```

Nothing else just these code were enough.